# can i combine java8 (stream, lambda) and guava?

Tags: java, lambda, guava, java-stream

When dealing with transformations(e.g: transform `List<People> people` to `List<Integer> ages`, where `People` is a class that contains a property `age`), normally there are 2 ways (for me) of doing this:

1. use java8:

   `people.stream().map(p -> p.getAge()).collect(toList())`;
2. or user guava2:

   `Lists2.transform(people, People2AgeTransformer.INSTANCE);` where the `People2AgeTransformer` is a transformer that implements the Function interface to return the age.

Recently, i accidentlly found that java8 and guava can be combined and therefore the code can be :

```
Lists2.transform(people, p->p.getAge());
```

this piece of code complies and runs OK without any error, which get me confused.
The method `Lists2.transform()` requires the 2nd args to be the implementation of interface `com.google.common.base.Function`, while the java8 lambda is actually the implementation of interface `java.util.function.Function`.(Well, they both declares a method `B apply(A input)` to transform A to B.)

I don't understand why this would work since they are two different interface of different package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> the java8 lambda is actually the implementation of interface `java.util.function.Function`

No it's not. `p -> p.getAge()` does not have a predefined type - its type is *inferred* at compile time depending on the context in which it's called. Any functional interface that has a `int/Integer getAge(Person p)` method will work.

So both `java.util.Function<Person, Integer>` and `com.google.common.base.Function<Person, Integer>` are compatible.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function assigned to variable or passed via parameter, it's really easy to adapt them via Java-8 method references:

```
java.util.function.Function<Person, Integer> javaFunction = p -> p.getAge();
com.google.common.base.Function<Person, Integer> guavaFunction = javaFunction::apply;
java.util.function.Function<Person, Integer> javaFunction2 = guavaFunction::apply;
```

So if you already have Java 8 `Function` object in variable `fn` and need to pass it into some Guava code, just use `fn::apply`. If you have Java 8 `Predicate` in variable `pred`, use `pred::test` when passing it into Guava code. Similar method references could be used for other functional interfaces.